# PK-chunking alternative for unsupported objects?

Tags: rest-api, bulk-api

I'm trying to do some queries through the Bulk API, and I'd like to use the PK Chunking Header.

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/async_api_headers_enable_pk_chunking.htm):

> PK chunking is supported for the following objects: Account, Campaign, CampaignMember, Case, Contact, Lead, LoginHistory, Opportunity, Task, User, and custom objects.

Is there an alternative way for the rest of the (unsupported) objects? I'd be interested in `Product2`, `PricebookEntry`, and `Pricebook2`.

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to accomplish? Difficult to suggest an alternative when we do not know your aim.

Comment: Oh, I apologize. I'm trying to use the Bulk API... I will edit my question.

Comment: BTW they added Product2, PricebookEntry and Pricebook2 support for PKChunking in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

You can split the query that is failing (since you need to use PKChunking, I assume your query is failing with with "InternalServerError, retried more than 15 times") into smaller queries - e.g. split your data by CreatedDate, execute 1 bulk query for each date range.